# Access 2007 How to hide #error from showing up on form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an expression:

```
(Current Year / Last Year ) - 1
```

This gives me the current year's **% change**.

If a new person joins, the database will not have data for **Last Year,**

This causes an **#Error** to show up on the **form** for that field. I don't want this to show up is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `IIf` expression in your query to return the calcalculed value when `[Last Year]` is not Null, and return Null when `[Last Year]` is Null.

```sql
SELECT
    IIf(Nz([Last Year], 0) > 0,
        ([Current Year] / [Last Year]) - 1,
        Null
        ) AS percent_change
FROM YourTable;
```